# malloc returns pointer to allocated memory

Tags: c, malloc

It's a long time since I've written C. My understanding is that `malloc` returns a pointer to a newly allocated memory region which does not overlap with previously `malloc`ed reactions. However, my program (below) seems to show `malloc` returning a pointer to the middle of an already allocated region!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
  int* bla;
  int baz;
  int qux;
  int bar;
} foo;

int main() {
  foo* foo = malloc(sizeof(foo));
  int* arr = malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);
  // my understanding of malloc is that `foo` and `bar` now point to
  // non-overlapping allocated memory regions

  printf("arr          %p\n", arr);            // but these print
  printf("&(foo->bar)  %p\n", &(foo->bar));    // the same address

  foo->bar = 42;
  printf("arr[0] = %d\n", arr[0]);   // prints 42

  return 0;
}
```

I am compiling and running this with:

```
$ cc --version
Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.29)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.3.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
$ cc     main.c   -o main
$ ./main
arr          0x7fa68bc03210
&(foo->bar)  0x7fa68bc03210
arr[0] = 42
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: using the recommended pattern `p = malloc(sizeof *p);` would have avoided this error

Comment: He could have happily done `foo *foo = malloc (sizeof *foo);`

Comment: `foo *foo = (foo *)malloc(sizeof(foo))` would have avoided the problem too, as the compiler now gives an error for `(foo *)`. Some posters like to say "don't cast malloc" but forget the second part of the advice (changing the `sizeof` expression). `malloc(sizeof(Type))` is more prone to errors than `(Type *)malloc(sizeof(Type))` and this question shows why.

Comment: when calling the function: `malloc()`, 1) do not cast the returned value. the return type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting the returned value just clutters the code making it more difficult to understand, debug, maintain.  2) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is that?!

```
foo* foo = malloc(sizeof(foo));
```

Please use different identifiers!

```
foo* variable = malloc(sizeof(foo));
```

Just to get sure I tested this `main()`:

```
int main() {
    printf("sizeof(foo)=%zu\n", sizeof(foo));
    foo* foo = malloc(sizeof(foo));
    printf("sizeof(foo)=%zu\n", sizeof(foo));
}
```

output (64bits with [LLP64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models)):

```
sizeof(foo)=24
sizeof(foo)=8
```

Don't use twice the same identifier, you get bad surprises.

Comment: Oh *of course*! `sizeof` can be applied to types and variables! What was I thinking? I wish `Wall` warned me about me this!

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin My main concern is even with `-Wextra` `-Wall` my gcc compile his code with no warning at all.

Comment: @jameshfisher Yes, I am also concerned by the absence of warning.

Comment: There is no warning generated. `sizeof (foo)` is 100% valid, it is the `sizeof (foo *)` (a pointer).

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin it's valid but very confusing, so a warning could be accurate.

Comment: A "don't do it" warning - yes, but not a compiler warning. All the compiler cares about is valid code. If you want to confuse yourself with the way you write it and in your choice of names, the compiler is OK with that -- anyone who reads your code may need Aspirin, but the compiler doesn't care `:)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin If I use a function returning an int and taking only int as arguments I can compile,link and run with no errors and only a warning during compilation for implicit declaration. "don't do it" is the meaning of a compiler warning, in several cases a warning is raised but there is no error.

Comment: We may be having language difficulty. The *"don't do it"* warning was meaning a common-sense warning between programmers, not anything related to the compiler. You can grab my code below and compile with full warnings `-Wall -Wextra` and you will get no warnings at all. (adding `-pedantic` will complain about the `printf` failure to cast to `void *`, but that is irrelevant to anything we are discussing.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin What I am trying to explain is a compiler could decide to raise a warning just to warn about the ambiguity of `sizeof(foo)` in the question's program. You can declare variables and never use them, this is poor programming but no error at all, so you get warnings with `-Wall`. What warnings are raised or not is not specified by standard, it's mostly the choice of compiler's designers.

Comment: Yes, Yes, I get that. That would be nice in some instances, but a pain in others. I'm happy with a minimal approach to how chatty the compiler is. I would much rather them put more time into more detailed messages about true errors and warnings where the code may fail, rather than where it could be less than optimally named. But Mohr's law is alive and well, who knows, 2 years from now the compiler may be doing just that!

Answer (score 1):

There is no collision between the `typdef` alias and declaration of an instance as the same name. You can, but not recommended, do what you had originally, but take the size from the variable instead of attempting to get it from the type. Specifically:

```
    foo *foo = malloc (sizeof *foo);
```

You can confirm in the full example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    int *bla;
    int baz;
    int qux;
    int bar;
} foo;

int main (void) {

    foo *foo = malloc (sizeof *foo);
    int *arr = malloc (sizeof *arr * 10);

    printf ("arr          %p\n", arr);
    printf ("&(foo->bar)  %p\n", &(foo->bar));

    foo->bar = 42;
    printf ("foo->bar = %d\n", foo->bar);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Output**

```
$ ./bin/foofoo
arr          0x17f3030
&(foo->bar)  0x17f3020
foo->bar = 42
```

Answer (score 0):

using the following code

Notice the unique name for the instance of `foo`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
  int* bla;
  int baz;
  int qux;
  int bar;
} foo;

int main()
{
  foo* myfoo = malloc(sizeof(foo));
  int* arr = malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);

  // my understanding of malloc is that `foo` and `bar` now point to
  // non-overlapping allocated memory regions

  printf("arr          %p\n", arr);            // but these print
  printf("&(foo->bar)  %p\n", &(myfoo->bar));    // the same address

  myfoo->bar = 42;
  printf("arr[0] = %d\n", arr[0]);   // prints 42

  return 0;
}
```

the output is:

```
arr          0x1578030
&(foo->bar)  0x1578020
arr[0] = 0
```

which is exactly what I would expect.

I compiled this under ubuntu linux 14.04 with gcc 4.8.4

using:

```
gcc -ggdb -c -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wconversion -std=gnu99 myfile.c -o mybile.o
```

then

```
gcc -ggdb -std=gnu99 myfile.o -o myfile
```

then ran it with

```
./myfile
```